# Execute same stored procedure from multiple datasets with different parameters in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dataset

I am trying to write a report that calls the same stored procedure in multiple datasets with different parameters.  Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: how about you pass multiple parameters to the same SP and then separate out the results  in the report? That way you only run the SP once! but then I don't have the context of the question or why you want to run it multiple times etc.. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, and that naturally seems like the most obvious solution, however the stored procedure returns a result set with sales from various departments.  My issue is I'm using these results in a graph and I have to calculate a trend line in the stored procedure (shocking SSRS does not provide a linear trend line).  This keeps me from doing a larger dataset and separating it our in SSRS.  I would drop the SQL into the dataset itself, however, it is using some advanced functions not supported by SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this our by using sub reports in SSRS.  I created a base report with the chart I needed.  I then created a sub report and added the base report multiple times.  Each sub report allowed me to pass in individual parameters.